# I am not able to set the og:title and og:description using react helmet and i am using Create React App(CRA). I am using Cloudflare CDN for hosting

Tags: reactjs, seo, facebook-opengraph, react-helmet, api-linkpreview

When I use Facebook developer debug tools to find out how my og title and og description is set

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

I got below result in the Facebook debug tool which is actually in the index.html file of our React App instead of getting it from using our Helmet component inside our react app:

It Shows this result which is actually in our index.html file

```
og:title    Blog Web

og:description  Blog Your Opinion
```

What I want it to show through Helmet

```
import { Helmet, HelmetProvider } from 'react-helmet-async';
```

I am doing using this library

Comment: I don't believe the Facebook crawler executes JavaScript.

Comment: @TonyMcCreath so what should i do?